Avoiding provider startup in NestJS tests
When i create a new module in NestJS i prefer testing the entire module as a component test. this means that i start the test with -
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [MyAppModule],
    })

I'd like to override providers that MyAppModule (or one of it's imports) defines, however, it seems their startup code still run, even when i explicitly provide it using
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide: ClassWithStartupCode, useValue: {}}] //option 1
      imports: [MyAppModule],
    }).
.overrideProvider(ClassWithStartupCode) //option 2
.useValue({})

is there any way for the provider to be mocked before MyAppModule is being initiated? is there a better pattern to do this?

What did you mean about their startup code still run? When you use option2, your provider was be mocked by useValue at runtime.
